# How to install samba client on ubi9 docker image?

Tags: docker, redhat

I'm building a docker image for a quarkus app using the [Red Hat ubi9 openjdk17 image](https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/ubi9/openjdk-17/61ee7c26ed74b2ffb22b07f6).

I am trying to install samba and samba-client using `microdnf install samba-client` but I'm getting this error:

```
error: No package matches 'samba-client'
```

I know it's probably a problem with the image's repo with it being a very small image, is there a way around this without changing the image?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/openjdk-17:1.15-2

USER root

# Download certificate and update ca-trust
RUN curl --output /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/mycert.crt \
    --create-dirs http://orgurl/rootcacert.pem \
    && update-ca-trust enable; update-ca-trust extract

# Update packages and install samba-related packages
RUN microdnf update -y && \
    microdnf install -y samba-client && \
    microdnf clean all

(ARGs and ENV variables...)

ENV LANGUAGE='en_US:en'

# We make four distinct layers so if there are application changes the library layers can be re-used
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/
COPY --chown=185 privateKey.pem /deployments/app/privateKey.pem

EXPOSE 8080

USER 185

ENV AB_JOLOKIA_OFF=""
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
ENV JAVA_APP_JAR="/deployments/quarkus-run.jar"
```